# Integrating Laravel Spark with Backpack

Tags: laravel-spark

This is probably a silly question as i am just starting out with laravel.
I have a laravel spark project with laravel backpack up and running.
I would like to use the users and teams functionality within backpack to limit what users can see/do depending on spark permissions.
How can i bring laravel spark functions/references into backpack so for example being able to pull the users team name.
Thanks so much!